# HTML CSS table fill space in parent element

Tags: html, css, formatting, width, css-tables

I use tables inside tables. I want that the child table fills the parent table cell. Is this possible?

Also, is it possible for a table column to fill the remaining space without shrinking the other columns (not like `width='90%'` which may force some other columns to get truncated)?

Comment: Is it possible? Probably. Is it possible in your code? Dunno, post your code.

Answer (score 4):

I guess these can help you: http://jsfiddle.net/B26zm/

1. When you give `width:100%` to a table, it will fill the width of its parent cell.
2. You need to define a width for the table, and width for all columns 'except' the one you need to be flexible. That way, the column with no width, will expand/shrink to match the width you define for the table.